# FormatException (FormatException: Invalid date format)

Tags: json, flutter, parsing

It seems that my string is not a valid format to parse the DateTime i can't seem to understand where the culprit is.
This happen from time to time when the app initiate the data.

error code :

```
  initListOfUsageValues() async {
    if (favoriteBike != null) {
      int periodWanted;
      if (displayedUsageType == "year") {
        periodWanted = displayedYear;
      } else if (displayedUsageType == "month") {
        periodWanted = displayedMonth;
      } else {
        periodWanted = displayedWeek;
      }
      List<int> list = await APIBike().getUsageData(
        jwt: _user!.jwt,
        bikeId: favoriteBike!.id,
        year: displayedYear,
        duration: displayedUsageType,
        periodWanted: periodWanted,
      );
      //The received list is in seconds so we need to convert it in minute
      list = convertSecondsToMinute(list);
      setState(() {
        listOfUsageValues = list;
      });
    } else {
      print("favoriteBike null in initListOfUsageValues");
      //check if the alertdialog saying that there is no bike linked to this account yet has been displayed already or no
      final storage = new FlutterSecureStorage();
      String lastNoBikeAlertShowUp =
          await storage.read(key: "last_no-bike-alert_show-up") ?? "";
      //If there is more than 60 minutes since last show up, we show the alertdialog saying that there is no bike linked to this account yet, else we don't
      DateTime lastNoBikeAlertShowUpDateTime =
          DateTime.parse(lastNoBikeAlertShowUp);
      var now = new DateTime.now();
      int timeInMinuteSinceLastAlertShowUp =
          now.difference(lastNoBikeAlertShowUpDateTime).inMinutes;
      if (timeInMinuteSinceLastAlertShowUp > 60) {
        await storage.write(
            key: "last_no-bike-alert_show-up", value: now.toString());
        showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return noBikeYetAlertDialog(context);
            });
      }
    }
  }
```

The error is trigered in this line :

```
      DateTime lastNoBikeAlertShowUpDateTime =
          DateTime.parse(lastNoBikeAlertShowUp);
```

Comment: Probably when the null aware operator provides an empy string `?? ""` . But why wouldn't you just add some logging?

Comment: sorry i'm kinda starting on flutter do you talk about custom loggin with dart:developper command ?

Comment: No, just some good old fashioned `print` statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lastNoBikeAlertShowUp is empty string. Because you see break on trow FormatException inside of date_time.dart

```
// set default date or check if it is not empty
String lastNoBikeAlertShowUp = await storage.read(key: "last_no-bike-alert_show-up") ?? "";
if(lastNoBikeAlertShowUp.isNotEmpty){

}
```

Comment: Hello, i tried but this didn't work for me unless you need to add something more in the " if " brackets ?

Comment: Of course, your whole code should be inside of this "if" after you read lastNoBikeAlertShowUp, this is the aim of "if". You will decide what you want on "else" if lastNoBikeAlertShowUp is empty